# Sphinx-js can't find class documentation

Tags: javascript, python-sphinx

I'm trying to setup sphinx_js but I keep receiving this error:

```
~/test_sphinx_js$ sphinx-build  -b html docs/source/ docs/build/html/
Running Sphinx v4.4.0
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [html]: targets for 1 source files that are out of date
updating environment: [new config] 1 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] index                                                                                                                                                                                    
Sphinx error:
No documentation was found for object "SomeClass" or any path ending with that.
```

this is my test project structure:

```
.
├── docs
│   ├── build
│   │   └── html
│   ├── make.bat
│   ├── Makefile
│   └── source
│       ├── conf.py
│       ├── index.rst
│       ├── _static
│       └── _templates
└── src
    └── SomeClass.js
```

and these are the relevant settings and code:

conf.py

```
[...]
extensions = ['sphinx_js']
js_source_path = '../../src'
primary_domain = 'js'
[...]
```

index.rst:

```
Welcome to SomeDocs's documentation!
====================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:



Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`

.. js:autoclass:: SomeClass
```

SomeClass.js:

```
/** Class representing something. */
export default class SomeClass {

    /**
     * Create class.
     * @param {string} name - The name of the object.
     * @param {string} type - The type of object.
     */
    constructor(name, type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;

    }
}
```

I must be missing something obvious but I can't wrap my head around it

Answer (score 0):

js:autoclass does not know how to parse 'export default class...'.  You can declare your class without prepending 'export default' and after the the class declaration a separate line can declare 'export default SomeClass', if you really need to export the class.